# The p5.js library functions aren't working with javascript class functions?

Tags: p5.js

I'm using the p5 library for my code, and it seems to break when I try to create a class function using a library function. I went on the reference page, and even the example class functions there use library functions, so I know I'm the one doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Here's my code:

```
class Enemy {
  constructor(x, y, radius, health) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.health = health
    this.r = radius
    this.show();
  }
//  this breaks on strokeWeight();
  show() {
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    noFill();
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2;
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: strokeWeight is not defined (sketch: line 11)
```

It says that each function is not defined when I try to comment out `strokeWeight();`, `stroke();`, `noFill();`, or `ellipse();`. If you can help, please do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to put the class after `setup()` but before the initialization of objects in the class.